# PLS-00323 error in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I am creating a procedure in a package. I have updated the specification of the package and then when i am updating the body of the package it shows me the following error.

> [Error] PLS-00323 (314: 13): PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'INSERT_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

N.B.: INSERT_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS is my procedure name.

Comment: Might be too obvious, but doublecheck if the procedure name is exactly the same, as well as all the parameters it receives.

Comment: Got it, just a letter missed from a parameter name.

Comment: same error here around half an hour dealing with that. thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to check return type too. That's what got me.

Comment: Please select a solution from below and mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a procedure in the package specification it must be created\implemented in the package body. Consider your package specification as an interface and the package body as its implementation.

Comment: Yes, I have added the procedure code in the package body. That is not the cause for error. Somehow when I update the procedure body it does not include the new procedure, although it is inside the package body.

Comment: It seems like a strange error. Everything is fine, still it it not creating.

Answer (score 2):

**Always the declaration on the pkg spec and the pkg body should be same.**

Which means the procedure / function declared in pkg spec ( includes name of the procedure / function , Parameter type ) should be exactly same.

Note : when oracle compiles the pkg for above error case, it won't give you the exact line no.

Comment: It looks like the problem was already solved in the comments, and you're just rehashing the comments into this answer.

Comment: The _Note_ is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Specification :  FUNCTION ITEM_ACTIVE(**SKU_NUM** IN NUMBER) RETURN BOOLEAN;

Body : FUNCTION ITEM_ACTIVE(**P_SKU_NUM** IN NUMBER) RETURN BOOLEAN;

Change either specification or body to match exact.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Because somebody's old errors are always news to me, I'll add my 3 cents:

Someone deleted their spec, but still had the body (No, I don't know how) and they "didn't want to have to type all that back in".

So I showed them how to generate the spec from the body:

1. Copy the body into a worksheet.
2. Insert an empty header above the body with the name of the package.
3. Compile.
4. [Whether you get an error or not,] Right click on the package body in the Packages tree, and select "Synchronize Specification and Body".
5. Select which objects to expose in the spec and click OK.
6. "magic happens"

Only magic didn't happen -- and everything went red...  with PLS-00323 errors.

SQL Developer populates the package spec by pulling the procedure and function headers from the code itself, so you shouldn't have to worry about things liek pselling.  It presents a list of objects to add to the package/spec, and you choose which ones to add.

We selected the correct procedures and functions, but it compiled with errors.  Again.  And, again.

It turns out that the functions that threw errors were defined in the package body with DETERMINISTIC -- when SQL Dev's editor did the synchronization, it left out the word.  That's pretty significant.

Anyway, reviewed, pasted DETERMINISTIC in the specific functions before the semi-colon, saved (recompiled), and then it was magic again.

You would expect SQL Developer to do the full job, instead of a half-... job.